# Parsing then checking if there is more in R

Tags: r, parsing

```
    Name             Parsed      Rank
WBA-Y*08:03:01    WBA-Y*08:03      1
WBA-Y*08:169      WBA-Y*08:169     2
WBA-Y*08:03:15    WBA-Y*08:03      3
WBA-Y*08:03:02    WBA-Y*08:03      4
```

These are three specific columns from my data frame. I have parsed through the name column and ordered/ranked them according to other values. I am now trying to parse and get the ones that have a third number and third colon then move the rest to the bottom.

Here is my expected output with this example:

```
    Name             Parsed      Rank
WBA-Y*08:03:01    WBA-Y*08:03      1
WBA-Y*08:03:15    WBA-Y*08:03      2
WBA-Y*08:03:02    WBA-Y*08:03      3
WBA-Y*08:169      WBA-Y*08:169     4
```

Since WBA-Y*08:169 only has two numbers and one colon this would be moved to the bottom. How do I do this? Can I use gsub or sub?

Comment: If the format is going to be like this, then you can simply count the `:` for each value. As 1 `:` means 2 numbers, 2 `:` means 3 numbers, etc. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `base R` option to fix it.  Use `grepl` to check for patterns where two digits followed by `:` two times followed by one or more numbers at the end (`$`) of the string in the 'Name' column, use this to `order` the first and second column and update those columns

```
df[1:2] <- df[order(-grepl("(\\d{2}:){2}\\d+$", df$Name)), 1:2]
df
#            Name       Parsed Rank
#1 WBA-Y*08:03:01  WBA-Y*08:03    1
#2 WBA-Y*08:03:15  WBA-Y*08:03    2
#3 WBA-Y*08:03:02  WBA-Y*08:03    3
#4   WBA-Y*08:169 WBA-Y*08:169    4
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("WBA-Y*08:03:01", "WBA-Y*08:169", "WBA-Y*08:03:15", 
"WBA-Y*08:03:02"), Parsed = c("WBA-Y*08:03", "WBA-Y*08:169", 
"WBA-Y*08:03", "WBA-Y*08:03"), Rank = 1:4), .Names = c("Name", 
"Parsed", "Rank"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! Can you explain to me this part "(\\d{2}:){2}\\d+$"? Also why is it minus grepl instead of just grepl?

Comment: @nathan By default, `order` goes by the alphabetic order for the logical vector derived from `grepl` that is `FALSE` followed by `TRUE`.  We can either use `decreasing = TRUE` argument (default is `FALSE`) or `-` to change the order.  The `\\d{2}` is two digits folowed by `:` as it is repeating twice we wrap it in brackets and use `{2}`

Answer (score 2):

```
df = read.table(text = "
Name             Parsed      Rank
WBA-Y*08:03:01    WBA-Y*08:03      1
WBA-Y*08:169      WBA-Y*08:169     2
WBA-Y*08:03:15    WBA-Y*08:03      3
WBA-Y*08:03:02    WBA-Y*08:03      4
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(v_Name = str_count(Name, ":")) %>%  # count how many : you have for each Name value
  arrange(desc(v_Name)) %>%                  # arrange descending by those counts
  mutate(Rank = row_number())                # update rank to be the row number

#             Name       Parsed Rank v_Name
# 1 WBA-Y*08:03:01  WBA-Y*08:03    1      2
# 2 WBA-Y*08:03:15  WBA-Y*08:03    2      2
# 3 WBA-Y*08:03:02  WBA-Y*08:03    3      2
# 4   WBA-Y*08:169 WBA-Y*08:169    4      1
```

You can remove `v_Name` if you want by adding `%>% select(-v_Name)` in the end.

Comment: Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function", which doesn't make sense since v_Name stores the function correct?

Comment: Was that an error when you tried to run this example or your full dataset?

Comment: Thats a good point I think that was my full data set,I'll try this again